# Meteor Publish/Subscribe best practice

Tags: meteor

Trying to understand some best practises with regards to Meteor.

I want to show a product list per user. I can think of two ways to show the products per user.

- Method 1: publishing only the products for this user and in the helper use the find({}) method to display all of them
- Method 2: publishing all products for all users and in the helper filter out the products for the current user using find({'userid' : this.userId}).

I have a preference for method 1 as it means sending much less data between server and client, but I see people often also use method 2.

Is Method 1 the best practice?

Source code below just for information.

Method 1:

```
//Templates
Template.products.onCreated(function() {
      var self = this;
      self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('products');
      });
    });


Template.products.helpers({
  getProducts: function () {
    return Products.find({}, { sort: { lastname: -1 }});
  }
});
//Publication
Meteor.publish('products', function () {
   return Products.find({'userid' : this.userId});
});
```

Method 2:

```
//Templates
Template.products.onCreated(function() {
      var self = this;
      self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('products');
      });
    });


Template.products.helpers({
  getProducts: function () {
    return Products.find({'userid' : this.userId}, { sort: { lastname: -1 }});
  }
});


//Publication    
Meteor.publish('products', function () {
  return Products.find();
});
```

Comment: "Best practice" according to what, who? Is it for performance? Sending as few data as possible to the client? Avoid multiple subscriptions? If it is just about the "general best practice", then it is opinion-based and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer is **both**.

**method 1**

In most cases, you'll want to ship only the necessary documents to the client for two reasons:

1. security - you may not want any user to open up a console and see the products for another user.
2. bandwidth/performance - the fewer documents you need to transmit and track on the server, the better your performance will be. There is a caveat to this, where you'll end up with 0 [observer reuse](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/improve-cpu-and-network-usage) for that publisher, but that may be outweighed by the previous points.

**method 2**

I **strongly recommend** always filtering in your template helpers. If your helper means "Only show the current user's products", then you absolutely should add that selector in your calls to `find`. The reason for this has to do with code maintenance.

Let's say 6 months from now you end up publishing additional products documents for some unrelated reason. If you didn't have the above selector, your template could do the wrong thing and show products for another user.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few considerations that will influence which approach to use.

For example, if the product lists are considered private information, you shouldn't use method 2 because every user's product list will be sent to every client. On the other hand, having one giant publication (method 2) can simplify your code. For instance, you could subscribe once at startup (for example) and not have to worry about managing subscriptions on a route by route or template by template basis like you would with method 1.

As you've already identified, another consideration is the size of the published Product collection. In general, try to limit the amount of data sent down to the client while keeping your code maintainable.

Hope that helps.